# Angularjs directive how to detect changes in the attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

I use jquery ui and angularjs in my project. I have a directive like so.

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.datepicker({
            altField: "#d" + attrs.fieldname + "_alt",
            altFormat: attrs.dateformat,
          });
        }
    };
```

I use it like.

```
<div fieldname="{{field.name}}" dateformat="{{field.dateformat}}" datepicker></div>
```

It works fine. But if the attrs changes, the changes are not reflected in datepicker. I was wondering if I could use something like this..

```
<div fielddata="field" datepicker></div>
```

And in the directive use `scope{ data: "=fielddata"}` and in my link function instead of `attrs.fieldname` use `scope.data.fieldname`

I appreciate any help

Comment: Could you consider using the Angular UI library, for example https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add watches to do what you want. Using the `scope: {}` as above does add watches under the hoods to synchronize the isolated scope of the directive with the external data. But since you are using jQueryUI, you need to take custom action on every change, so just add the watch yourself. E.g.:

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.datepicker({
                altField: "#d" + attrs.fieldname + "_alt",
                altFormat: attrs.dateformat,
            });

            attrs.$observe('dateformat', function(newval) {
                element.datepicker('option', 'altFormat', newval);
            });

            // and so on for every attribute
        }
    };
});
```

`attrs.$observe` will work for interpolated attributes, i.e. attributes with `{{...}}` expressions. You may want to use `$parse` and `scope.$watch` if you want to pass complex objects to your directive.